# HTML - HR Tag (Horizontal Line)

Tags: html, formatting, lines

Question 1: How do I remove formatting on HR lines so they are just plain lines? Currently, they look like this: http://i.imgbomb.com/yyEGj.png. As you can see, they have a bit of formatting or style. Almost double layered. I want it to look like this: http://i.imgbomb.com/WtwTB.png

Comment: That's a typical question of 'hr' element. There are plenty of examples in the network. Even the first result I get: http://www.sovavsiti.cz/css/hr.html from google under 'HR formatting' gives you an answer.

Comment: No matter how I change it using CSS there is still some weird box type thing on the sides.

Comment: Are you sure the css is even applied? Anyway, that's hard to advice anything if you don't see any particular code (html or css) provided.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also and I used this to get it back to just a 1px line:

```
border: none;
color:#000000;
background-color:#000000;
height:1px;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2k7w/)